# How use Subview for model with relations

Tags: ember.js

How to best display model in Ember like Day each day contain list of Races.
So model with has many relation to other model.

In HTML I would like display it like

```
- Day 1
-- Race 1
-- Race 2
- Day 2
-- Race 3
-- Race 4
```

I am interesting how to organize Controllers and Views?

Btw, would be great to have examples of all relations in Ember doc: one to one, one to many, many to many.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have an array of Days, and then an Array of Races within each day.  Let me know if you need help on actually loading the datasource as well.  But the main piece of this is the template.

```
# models

Race = Ember.Object.extend({
    raceNumber: null
})

Day = Ember.Object.extend({
    dayNumber: null
    races: []
})

# controller
daysController = Ember.View.create({

  init: ->
    @loadDays()

  content: null

  loadDays: ->
    # load your days and your races here
    content = YOUR DATA GOES HERE
})

# view

DayView = Ember.View.extend({

    templateName: 'days'

    daysBinding: daysController.content

})

# template

script(type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='days')
  ul
    {{#each day in view.days}}
      li day.dayNumber
      li ul
            {{each race in day.races}}
              li race.raceNumber
            {{/each}}
     {{/each}}
```